# Is Adi Shankaracharya's commentary (some parts) Arthavāda?

Tags: adi-shankaracharya, commentary

Is adi shankaracharya's commentary(some parts) ARTHAVĀDA?

For example :

> The ignorant following the diverse ways of ignorance, flatter themselves that their objects have been accomplished. As these followers of karma do not learn the truth owing to their desire, they grow miserable and after the fruits of their karma are consumed, fall from Heaven. These ignorant men regarding sacrificial and charitable acts as most important, do not know any other help to bliss; having enjoyed in the heights of Heaven the abode of pleasures, they enter again into this or even inferior world. (Mundaka Upanishad 1.2.9-10)
>
> *Shankara’s Commentary: ( 1.2.9)*
>
> Com.—The ignorant acting diversely according to ignorance, flatter themselves that they have achieved what they should. This being so, the followers of karma do not learn the truth as they are assailed with the desire for the fruits of karma; they grow miserable for that reason and fall from heaven after the fruits of their karma are consumed.
>
> *Shankara’s Commentary: ( 1.210)*
>
> Com.—“Ishtam” karma enjoined by the Srutis as sacrifices, etc. “Purtam” karma enjoined by Smritis such as the digging of pools, wells, tanks, etc. Regarding these alone as the most important aids to the attainment of human objects, these ignorant men, being infatuated with attachment to their sons, cattle and relatives, do not know the other called ‘knowledge of self’ which is the help to bliss. Having enjoyed in the top of heaven—the place of pleasures—the fruits of their karma, they enter again into this world of men or even inferior world, such as the world of horizontal beings, hell, etc., according to the residue of their karma.

So in these commentary adi shankara spoke about heaven, so can heaven be ARTHAVĀDA in these commentarys?

Comment: I do not see the logic of your question. Please clarify.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda I am asking is there ARTHAVĀDA in adi shankaracharya's commentary. Example I have give. I am also asking whether the commentary is ARTHAVĀDA or not

Comment: Which part do you specifically think is ArthvAda? Maybe bold-highlight them?

Comment: @Vivikta its not about part but in general.